# Convert a single DataRow (with strings and ints) into a List<string> c#

Tags: c#, datatable, casting

I have a DataRow with multiple string values and one id that is an int:

I want to make this DataRow into a List. I have tried it in the following way (`situationRisk` is my DataRow):

```
situationRisk.ItemArray.Cast<string>().ToList()
```

But this gives me an error that I cannot convert the System.Int64 id into a System.String.

Anyone know how to do this without looping over each element and adding them separately?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your mistake is that you don't want to *cast* the objects to a `string` but to *convert* them. The easiest way for your requirements would be something like:

```
situationRisk.ItemArray.Select(i => i.ToString()).ToList();
```

---

As Søren mentioned below, take care of `null` values in the `DataRow`. Depending on your requirements I'd suggest something like that:

```
situationRisk.ItemArray.Select(i => i?.ToString()).ToList();
```

which inserts the `null`s in the list or

```
situationRisk.ItemArray.Select(i => i?.ToString() ?? string.Empty).ToList();
```

which replaces them with empty strings.

Comment: Note however, if your `object[]` – `ItemArray` in your case – contains `null`  values, the `Select` will result in a `NullReferenceException`. To circumvent this problem you can opt for `.Select(i => Convert.ToString(i)).ToList()` instead.